# How to toggle mobile navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got a basic navbar for the mobile site only, but when click then it does nothing. As I want it where that you click the nav icon and it releases the navigation.

I have researched. for a solution, but nothing seems to work.

HTML

```
<span class="header-nav">
    <header ng-controller="Headerng-controller" mouseleave="hideHoverMenu()" class="scope" id="headerRoot">
        <div class="top">
            <a href="#" class="visible-xs visible-sm hamburger-menu-btn" ng-click="toggleMobileNav(scroll); $event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation()"></a>
<section id="siteMobileNav" class="visible-xxs visible-xs visible-sm blur-on-submit mobile-nav">
    <ul class="main-links">
        <li><a href="index" class="home-link" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Home">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="games" class="games-link" class="{active: section === &quot;games&quot;}" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Games">Games</a></li>

        <li><a href="videos" class="videos-link" class="{active: section === &quot;videos&quot;}" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Videos" style="">Videos</a></li>

        <li><a href="newswire" class="newswire-link" class="{active: section === &quot;newswire&quot;}" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Newswire">Newswire</a></li>

        <li><a href="//socialclub.galaxy-games.co.uk" class="socialclub-link" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Social Club">Social Club</a></li>

        <li><a href="downloads" ui-sref="downloads.index" class="downloads-link" class="{active: section === &quot;downloads&quot;}" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Downloads">Downloads</a></li>

        <li><a href="//www.Galaxywarehouse.com" class="warehouse-link" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Warehouse">Warehouse</a></li>

        <li><a href="//support.galaxy-games.co.uk" class="support-link" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Support">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="etc-links">
        <li class="etc">Et cetera</li>
        <li><a href="https://socialclub.galaxy-games.co.uk/settings/email" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Subscribe">Subscribe</a></li>

        <li><a href="/careers" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Careers">Careers</a></li>

        <li><a href="mailto:mouthoff@galaxy-games.co.uk" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Mouthoff">Mouthoff</a></li>

        <li><a href="mailto:PR@galaxy-games.co.uk" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Press">Press</a></li>

        <li><a href="/corpinfo" ui-sref="corpinfo" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Corporate Info">Corporate</a></li>

        <li><a href="/privacy" ui-sref="privacy" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Privacy">Privacy</a></li>

        <li><a href="/cookies" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Privacy">Cookies</a></li>

        <li><a href="/legal" ui-sref="legal" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Legal">Legal</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="language">
        <div click="mobileLang = !mobileLang" class="{active: mobileLang === true}" id="language-current">
            <span class="en_us">English</span>
        </div>
        <div class="{active: mobileLang === true}" class="language-selector">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=en_us" target="_self" data-language="en">English</a></li>

                <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=de_de" target="_self" data-language="de">Deutsch</a></li>

                <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=fr_fr" target="_self" data-language="fr">Français</a></li>

                <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=it_it" target="_self" data-language="it">Italiano</a></li>

                <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=ja_jp" target="_self" data-language="ja" class="bold">日本語</a></li>

                <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=ru_ru" target="_self" data-language="ru">РУССКИЙ</a></li>

                <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=es_es" target="_self" data-language="es">ESPAÑOL (ESPAÑA)</a></li>

                <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=es_mx" target="_self" data-language="es-mx">ESPAÑOL (MÉXICO)</a></li>

                <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=pt_br" target="_self" data-language="pt">PORTUGUÊS</a></li>

                <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=ko_kr" target="_self" data-language="ko">한국어</a></li>

                <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=zh_hans" target="_self" data-language="zh-hans" class="bold">中文（简体）</a></li>

                <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=zh_tw" target="_self" data-language="zh" class="bold">中文（繁體）</a></li>

                <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=pl_pl" target="_self" data-language="pl">POLSKI</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="social">
        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/Galaxygames" class="facebook" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Social Click" data-gtm-label="Facebook"></a></li>

        <li><a href="http://twitter.com/GalaxyGames" class="twitter" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Social Click" data-gtm-label="Twitter"></a></li>

        <li><a href="http://youtube.com/Galaxygames" class="youtube" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Social Click" data-gtm-label="YouTube"></a></li>

        <li><a href="http://instagram.com/Galaxygames" class="instagram" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Social Click" data-gtm-label="Instagram"></a></li>

        <li><a href="http://twitch.tv/Galaxygames" class="twitch" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Social Click" data-gtm-label="Twitch"></a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

CSS

```
header#headerRoot>.top a.hamburger-menu-btn{
    background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:15px;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
}
header#headerRoot a {
    text-decoration: none!important;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .visible-xs {
        display: block!important;
    }
}
.mobile-nav-shown #siteMobileNav {
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}

#siteMobileNav {
    position: fixed;
    box-shadow: inset -10px 3px 17px -16px rgba(50,50,50,.71);
    padding: 5px 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 270px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 100%;
    transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,-270,0);
}
@media screen and (max-width:991px){
    header#headerRoot>.top
    {
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;
        height:70px
    }
    header#headerRoot>.top nav
    {
        margin:0
    }
}
header#headerRoot>.top a.logo.logo-side{
    width:36px;
    position:absolute;
    left:15px;
    padding-top:16px;
    z-index:100;
    transform:matrix(1,0,0,1,0,-175);
    transition:transform .3s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1)
}
.header-collapsed header#headerRoot>.top a.logo.logo-side{
    transform:matrix(1,0,0,1,0,-8)
}
@media screen and (max-width:991px){
    header#headerRoot>.top a.logo.logo-side
    {
        display:none;
    }
}
header#headerRoot>.top a.logo.logo-main{
    z-index:20;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:650px;
    height:75px;
    margin:20px auto;
    position:absolute;
    transform:matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    transition:transform .3s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1)
}
.header-collapsed header#headerRoot>.top a.logo.logo-main{
    transform:matrix(.5,0,0,.5,0,-100)
}
@media screen and (max-width:991px){
    header#headerRoot>.top a.logo.logo-main
    {
        margin:0 auto;
        height:100%;
        padding:10px;
        transform:matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0) !important
    }
}
header#headerRoot>.top a.logo.white{
    background-position:50% !important
}
header#headerRoot>.bottom{
    z-index:20;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:100%;
    margin-top:-1px;
    transform:translateY(-1px)
}
header#headerRoot nav{
    z-index:20;
    position:relative;
    max-width:1920px;
    margin:99px auto 0;
    padding:0 15px;
    transition:margin-top .3s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
    font-size:1em;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden
}
@media screen and (max-width:991px){
    header#headerRoot nav
    {
        font-size:.9em
    }
}
.header-collapsed header#headerRoot nav{
    margin-top:0
}
header#headerRoot nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    vertical-align:top;
    float:none !important;
    color:inherit;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding:15px 0;
    position:relative;
    outline:none;
    transition:all .2s
}
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("main-links");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Mobile Nav Icon
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uuv2b.jpg

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance.

JSFiddle for this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/xth2j3bw/

Comment: Why not use https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/sidenav?

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work

Comment: "I have researched. for a solution, but nothing seems to work" Care to elaborate on what specific approaches you've tried?

Comment: @agrm Oh apologies, I have searched google, youtube and on here